# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.quartz.Scheduler.deleteTrigger(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Getting this error while trying to delete jon and trigger getting this error
below is my code

```
JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey(jobName);
        if (scheduler.checkExists(jobKey)) {
            log.info("job found for "+ jobName);
            boolean isdeletted = scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey(jobName));
            if (!isdeletted) {
                log.error("job not deleted");
            }
        }
        scheduler.unscheduleJob(new TriggerKey(triggerName));
```

please help me on this.
below is the starch trace

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: framwork.deleteTrigger(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at framwork
    at framwork
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at framwork
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy660.updatePartner(Unknown Source)
    at framwork
    at framwork
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at framwork
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
```

this stack trace of the error
please help

Comment: Add the exception you are getting plz

Comment: i just update my question. with stacktrace

Comment: @M.Mas. please help me. i am stuck with this deleting job and trigger

Answer (score 0):

`org.quartz.Scheduler#unscheduleJob` accepts the trigger key as parameter. Hence, you can remove the trigger specified (which is bound to  your job).

```
public static boolean removeJob(String jobName, String jobGroup) throws SchedulerException {
  TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey(jobName, jobGroup);
  if (scheduler.checkExists(triggerKey)) {
    scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey);    // trigger + job
  }
  logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>> removeJob success, triggerKey:{}", triggerKey);
  return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

***Useful* link:** https://www.baeldung.com/quartz

***UPDATE***

Back to the exception you are getting, the root cause is that you most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

Make sure you don't have several versions of `Quartz` in your classpath.
Try to clean you project et rebuild it if you are using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: i think new TriggerKey(triggerName) and TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey(jobName, jobGroup); statements are same. thats why i used this  new TriggerKey(triggerName) am i wrong?

Comment: and i didn't used group while creating job and trigger so i didnt mentioned here too. so it will take default group so no need to mention right?